# Use JScrollPane in JPanel and zoom a Graphics2D correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, jscrollpane

I have a problem with zoom `JPanel`. I have a circle in the middle of panel when I click a message say:

```
you clicked in the circle
```

And if I don't click on the circle it will be:

```
you're out of any circle
```

The problem I tried zoom the panel but now when I click the message says you're out of panel (but I'm clicking in the zoomed circle) also the `JScrollPane` don't work I tried hard with it but it don't working. Please help.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


public class ZoomProject extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Ellipse2D DraggedCircle;
    Ellipse2D CircleDrawInPanel;
    public ZoomProject() {
        initComponents();
        CircleDrawInPanel=new Ellipse2D.Float(jPanel1.getWidth()/2,jPanel1.getHeight()/2, 50, 50);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel(){
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                super.paintComponent(g);
                int w =getWidth(); // real width of canvas
                int h =getHeight(); // real height of canvas
                // Translate used to make sure scale is centered
                g2.translate(w/6, h/6);
                g2.scale((double)jSlider1.getValue(),(double)jSlider1.getValue());
                g2.translate(-w/6, -h/6);
                g2.fillOval(w/2,h/2,50,50);

            }
        };

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSlider1.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSlider.VERTICAL);
        jSlider1.setValue(1);
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 436, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 311, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 455, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 311, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
     if(CircleDrawInPanel.contains(evt.getPoint())){
        DraggedCircle=CircleDrawInPanel;
      System.out.println("You click the circle now");  
     }
     else
         System.out.println("Out of Circle");
    }                                    

    private void jPanel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(jPanel1.getWidth()*jSlider1.getValue(),jPanel1.getHeight()*jSlider1.getValue()));
        jScrollPane1.updateUI();
        repaint();
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ZoomProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ZoomProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ZoomProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ZoomProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ZoomProject().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```